# Angular & TypeScript - How to bind an ngModel to a dynamic key of an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a type `WeeklyDriver` with some keys, and I want to iterate over an array of `WeeklyDriver` objects (`drivers` in my example), and then over a specific set of `keyof WeeklyDriver`:

```
public ovrKeys:Array<keyof WeeklyDriver> = [
    'SunOvrVal',
    'MonOvrVal',
    'TueOvrVal',
    'WedOvrVal',
    'ThuOvrVal',
    'FriOvrVal',
    'SatOvrVal'
];
```

Here is my declaration of `drivers`:

```
@Input() drivers:Array<WeeklyDriver> = [];
```

Note that the value each of these keys is typed as a `number`, which may be what I'm doing wrong here given I am trying to bind to a `number` input, but I'm not aware of how to use TypeScript to designate that the `keyof WeeklyDriver` that I am using in that array are of type `number` as well.

I would like to loop over an array of `WeeklyDriver` objects, and then loop through those keys and bind to them in number inputs:

```
<tr *ngFor="let driver of drivers">
  <td *ngFor="let ovrKey of ovrKeys">
    <input
      type="number"
      min="0"
      step="1"
      [(ngModel)]="driver[ovrKey]"
      placeholder="New value"
    />
  </td>
</tr>
```

However I keep getting hit with this error:

`Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'`

And the error occurs specifically here:

```
[(ngModel)]="driver[ovrKey]"
```

I have tried using `as keyof WeeklyDriver` in my html as such `driver[ovrKey as keyof WeeklyDriver]` however got an error for missing ending `]` character.

I also tried doing `*ngFor="let (ovrKey as keyof WeeklyDriver) of ovrKeys"` but then I run into `Property 'ovrKey' does not exist on type 'WeeklyDriverTableComponent'. Did you mean 'ovrKeys'?`

What am I doing wrong here? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to provide your code that has the transpile error. It seems to work on [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjmbfm?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: The problem is how you define the array "drivers". It's looks like you declare as drivers=null or similar. you can declare an interface and use `drivers:Interface[]=[]`. You can use explicity all the variables or use `interface Interface {[key: string]: string;}`

Comment: @FrankFajardo @Eliseo added in my declaration of `drivers` as well as the exact line the error is occurring. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Raj, it is hard to tell where the problem is without a copy of your code that shows the error. Maybe you could look at the example I gave in my earlier comment and figure out why your code is not working.

Answer (score -1):

In your ts:

```
drivers: any[] = [{ name: "dr-1" }, { name: "dr-2" }];
public ovrKeys: Array<keyof typeof WeeklyDriver> = [
'SunOvrVal',
'MonOvrVal',
'TueOvrVal',
'WedOvrVal',
'ThuOvrVal',
'FriOvrVal',
'SatOvrVal'
];
```

and your html:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let driver of drivers">
    <td>{{driver.name}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let ovrkey of ovrKeys">
       <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="driver[ovrkey]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: while technically this does work, this defeats the whole purpose of using TypeScript. I'd like to preserve the typing of my variables and objects for debugging and intellisense purposes.

Comment: Modified the answer please change the ovrKeys type to  Array<keyof typeof WeeklyDriver>"

Comment: That still does not accomplish what I am trying to do here, using `keyof typeof` doesn't help as I already know what type I'm using, `WeeklyDriver`. `keyof typeof` here is redundant.